# VSCode bash terminal prints 'CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda' when opened

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, anaconda, git-bash

I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but I've downloaded VS code through Anaconda and I've downloaded git bash and set it as my default terminal in VS code. When for I run a python file in terminal, this error shows.
Conda version 6.11
VS code version 1.33.1 on Windows 10

Comment: The title of a question should be a *descriptive **title**,* and you should try to keep it to a single line (about 72 characters). A reader should be able to understand what you are asking by reading the question body by itself. Obviously that’s not the case here.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  For example, say what operating system you’re running.  (Add corresponding tag(s) as well.)  Identify the versions of Visual Studio Code and git bash you’re using.  Describe what you have done and what happens when.  I don’t understand what you mean by “at the start”.   And then maybe shorten your title.